# Can't resolved @ modules using webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

I would like to ask how should I get modules that begins with @ being resolved because all modules that aren't start with @ works without any error.

My webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const glob = require('glob');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = (env, options) => ({
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new UglifyJsPlugin({ cache: true, parallel: true, sourceMap: false }),
      new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({})
    ]
  },

  entry: {
    './js/app.js': ['./js/app.js'].concat(glob.sync('./vendor/**/*.js'))
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'app.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../priv/static/js')
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader']
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({ filename: '../css/app.css' }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([{ from: 'static/', to: '../' }])
  ]
});
```

My entry point js file:

```
import css from '../css/app.css';
import 'phoenix_html';
import 'spectre.css';
import '@yaireo/tagify';
```

Error message:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@yaireo/tagify' in '/home/hei/Desktop/elixir/pluma/assets/js'
 @ ./js/app.js 13:0-24
 @ multi ./js/app.js
```

Comment: what specific error are you getting?

Comment: @ztadic91 I updated my question.

Comment: maybe a stupid question, but is @yaireo properly installed(package.json) and in `node_modules`

Comment: Yes it is, I check it in node_modules folder and package.json and it was there.

Answer (score 0):

Import directly from the **src** folder inside the package.

```
import Tagify from "@yaireo/tagify/src/tagify";
```

Working [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/821146q179)

Comment: I'm not working with react right now so probably it will not work but I will try it later.

Comment: @RicardoRaz any luck?